# lua programming.attempt to index local 'self' (a nil value) ,stack traceback:

Tags: lua, coronasdk

The problem is in the function name "bullet Collision) 
I cannot remove the bullet after collision. If the line self:removeSelf() is removed then the code runs. The error shows just after the bullet collide with the enemy.

```
--Physics world creation

local physics = require ("physics")
physics.start()
physics.setGravity(1,1)

--screen
local width=display.contentWidth
local height=display.contentHeight

--game characters
local enemy
local hero
local bullet
local background
local score
local counter

--backGround
background= display.newImage("night_sky.png",width/2,height/2,true)


--collision filters
local heroCollisionFilter = { categoryBits=1, maskBits=2 }
local enemyCollisionFilter = { categoryBits=2, maskBits=7 }
local bulletCollisionFilter = { categoryBits=4, maskBits=2 }




--hero's death
function heroCollision(event)
end

--bullet heat
function bulletCollision(event, self)
    print("bullet collided")
    if event.other.name == "enemy" then
        self:removeSelf()
        event.other:removeSelf()
        event.other= nil

    end


end





--fire
function fireBullet(event)
    bullet=display.newImage("bullet.png",hero.x,hero.y )
    physics.addBody(bullet,{filter=bulletCollisionFilter})
    bullet.name=bullet
    local gx = event.x-bullet.x
    local gy = event.y-bullet.y
    physics.setGravity(gx/10,gy/10)
    bullet.collision= bulletCollision
    bullet:addEventListener("collision", bulletCollision)

end


function addEnemy()

    local enemy = display.newImage("ball.png",40,50)
    physics.addBody(enemy,{filter=enemyCollisionFilter})
    enemy.gravityScale=0
    enemy:addEventListener("tap",fireBullet)
    enemy.name= "enemy"
end

addEnemy()




background:addEventListener("tap", fireBullet)

hero = display.newImage("pearl1.png",width/2,height/2,true)
```

Comment: `function bulletCollision(event, self)` self is generally the first parameter passed

Comment: function bulletCollision(self,event) did not work :(

Comment: Replace `function bulletCollision(event, self)` with `function bullet:collision(event)` and `bullet:addEventListener("collision", bulletCollision)` with `bullet:addEventListener("collision", bullet)`, remove `bullet.collision= bulletCollision`

Comment: Yes that is working, thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't setting up the collision properly.

1. `bullet.collision` is correctly set to the collision function `bulletCollision` but you are not setting up the event listener correctly. You should do `bullet:addEventListener("collision", bullet)` instead of `bullet:addEventListener("collision", bulletCollision)`.
2. The event listener function for the "collision" event has the order of arguments switched around. It should be `(self, event)`, not `(event, self)`

All according to [the collision documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/api/event/collision/index.html).

```
function bulletCollision(self, event)
    print("bullet collided")
    if event.other.name == "enemy" then
        self:removeSelf()
        event.other:removeSelf()
        event.other= nil
    end
end

function fireBullet(event)
    bullet=display.newImage("bullet.png",hero.x,hero.y )
    physics.addBody(bullet,{filter=bulletCollisionFilter})
    bullet.name=bullet
    local gx = event.x-bullet.x
    local gy = event.y-bullet.y
    physics.setGravity(gx/10,gy/10)
    bullet.collision= bulletCollision
    bullet:addEventListener("collision", bullet)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm happy to hear that it worked with my suggestion. Could you please mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You need tho check the display object is null every time before remove such as:

```
if xxx ~= nil then
    xxx:removeSelf()
    xxx = nil
end
```